# How to configure Spring Boot to use a database failover solution?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp, failover

I have configured three data sources in my Spring Boot project, where the three data sources are equal and there are other components that automatically synchronize data between them to ensure consistency.

My requirement is to use Spring Boot + JPA + HikariCP framework to perform read/write operations on data source 1. When data source 1 encounters connection issues, it should automatically switch to data source 2 or data source 3. If data source 1 recovers, it should be added back to the list of available data sources. I am not sure if Spring Boot or HikariCP have built-in functionality for this, and I don't know how to implement it.

Here is my yml:

```yaml
spring.datasource.primary.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://primary_host:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.primary.username=user1
spring.datasource.primary.password=pass1

spring.datasource.secondary.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://secondary_host:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.secondary.username=user2
spring.datasource.secondary.password=pass2

spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=${spring.datasource.primary.jdbcUrl},${spring.datasource.secondary.jdbcUrl}
```

I have tried searching on Google but couldn't find a solution for this. I have also tried asking ChatGPT, but the methods provided were either problematic or not executable.

Comment: Now if that only would be documented on the MySQL driver page... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-config-failover.html. In short set the proper URL (yours isn't) and the proper driver properties.

Comment: @ M.Deinum the page was 404 now , can you provide again ?